# How do I make a part of the caption to be bold in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to make caption of WF in code.

```
DataRowView drv = bindingSource.Current as DataRowView;
string postOffice = drv["POST_OFFICE_NAME"].ToString();
Text = "Some text" + " [" + postOffice + "]";
```

How to bold this string "postOffice"(string in [] brackets)? It is part of the WF title.

[image]

Comment: How are you displaying it? Inside a label, a data grid, rendering it to HTML, printing it to a file? Please update your question with this key bit of information.

Comment: Assuming, that you are talking about `ListViewItem.Text`, you need to set `ListView.OwnerDraw = true` and then override `ListView.OnDrawItem(DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)`.

Comment: You cannot bold part of the window title. The window manager does not support that feature. You *could* handle `WM_NCPAINT` and such, but that's a lot of work and the look and feel of your application will feel off compared to the other windows.

Comment: Ok, after adding your picture i understand it like "How do I make part of the forms caption to be bold." This is not possible.

Comment: Ok, tnx. It is not so necessary, I was just wondering if this is possible.